# How to add inputs to a selector method

Tags: objective-c, selector

I'm trying this

```
[timePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(timeValueChanged:self.pickupTimeTextField datePicker:self.timePicker) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

But it gives me a syntax error. How can I pass through UITextField and UIDatePicker to the method in the selector.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing parameters to addTarget:action:forControlEvents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988485/passing-parameters-to-addtargetactionforcontrolevents)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the method *signature* in the `action` parameter.  You are attempting to pass parameters to the method, which doesn't make sense.

Try:

```
[timePicker addTarget:self
               action:@selector(timeValueChanged:datePicker:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a method with no parameter and you can use this method for target selector. Also in this method, you can call "timeValueChanged:datePicker:" method.

You may see this for detail: [Passing parameters to addTarget:action:forControlEvents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988485/passing-parameters-to-addtargetactionforcontrolevents)