# How to pass method parameters through addTarget

Tags: ios, methods, parameters, target

I'm adding a target to a `UISwitch`, I'd like to pass both the sender (`UISwitch`) and an object (`NSIndexPath`).

I'm not sure on the syntax for this, would be great if anyone could point me in the right direction

```
[certificateSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(certificateSwitcher:withIndexPath:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

method:

```
- (void)certificateSwitcher:(UISwitch *)sender withIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexpath
```

also before anyone says put the row number as the `UISwitch's` tag property, It's not an option, I have some other stuff that relies on the tag of the `UISwitch`

Thanks

Comment: You can use the solution provided in this answer regarding UIButton and passing mulitple parameters to its selector: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53779104/5324541

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot pass  your_Own value .

you should  use the `tag` property Or you can [subclassing the UISwitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988485/passing-parameters-to-addtargetactionforcontrolevents).