# Delegation in Swift - Error Cannot invoke addTarget with an argument list

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to use the delegation pattern in Swift and have got the following code:

```
protocol NumericViewDelegate {
    func one() 
}



class NumericView: UIView {

var delegate: NumericViewDelegate?

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    var oneButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 100.0, 200.0, 100.0))
    oneButton.titleLabel?.text = "one"
    oneButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    oneButton.addTarget(self.delegate!, action: "one:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpOutside)
    self.addSubview(oneButton)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder
    ) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code
}
*/

}
```

But declaring `self.delegate`! in `addTarget` doesn't work. I receive the error:

> Cannot invoke 'addTarget' with an argument list of type
>   '(NumericViewDelegate, action: String, forControlEvents:
>   UIControlEvents).

It works when declaring `self` in `addTarget`, but that's not the intended behaviour.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing parameters to addTarget:action:forControlEvents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988485/passing-parameters-to-addtargetactionforcontrolevents)

Comment: The link is not related at all. It works with self as target.

Comment: Is this error occurs at runtime or compile time ?

Comment: It occurs at compile time.

Comment: What argument does self.delegate.one take?

Comment: Which class confirms to this protocol and did you set numericViewObject.delegate = self in the class which confirms to this protocol?

Comment: Even if it were compiling, it won't work. You tried to pass your `delegate` variable to `addTarget()` method but it's on the `init` so `delegate` will **never** be other than `nil` at this time. You probably have to rethink how you do that.

Comment: No argument, but it's not related to the action, because compiling works with self no matter what I define as action. But it doesn't work with self.delegate!

Comment: How can I access a delegate method in addTarget then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
protocol NumericViewDelegate:NSObjectProtocol {
  func one()
}

class NumericView: UIView {

  var delegate: NumericViewDelegate?

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    var oneButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 100.0, 200.0, 100.0))
    oneButton.titleLabel?.text = "one"
    oneButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    oneButton.addTarget(self.delegate!, action: "one:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpOutside)
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.addSubview(oneButton)
  }

  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
  }
}
```

In this way, it will compile well, however, your delegate is nil in `init` - it means nothing.