# How to subclass an UIButton to pass multiple NSString parameters via addTarget:action:forControlEvents

Tags: parameters, uibutton, nsstring, action, addtarget

I have to programmatically define (without using any IBAction) a UIButton that when tapped gets the values of 3 NSString parameters and executes a Segue.
The method used for executing the Segue is called via:

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And then executed as:

```
-(void)myButtonTapped {
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showNewFromOld" sender:self];}
```

I understand that the best solution would be to subclass the UIButton (myButton in my case) in order to pass via the sender the 3 NSString as found in this answer:
[Passing parameters to addTarget:action:forControlEvents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988485/passing-parameters-to-addtargetactionforcontrolevents)
Unfortunately I cannot comment this given my newbie level and I would really appreciate some help from the community on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found simply involves the definition of a class method visible to other classes:

```
+(void)myMethod:...
```